# Magento 2 - Change font-size of element with LESS

Tags: magento2, less

I try to change the **font-size** of the element with class **box-content** in the customer area from **1.6rem** to **1rem**.

[image]

[image]

As you can see it shows that this is defined in **_module.less** Line #406 :

```
//
//  Desktop
//  _____________________________________________

.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
    .block-reviews-dashboard {
        .product-name {
            &:extend(.abs-account-block-font-size all);
        }
    }
}
```

The whole path is: **pub/static/frontend/hausfux/base/de_DE/Magento_Review/css/source/_module.less** but interestingly, there is no such file in `vendor/magento/module-review/view/web` there is not even a css folder... ???

**↑↑↑ EDIT**: Now I understand. The file is in `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma`, which is the Luma theme which I extend.

Im not sure why it leaded me to this code, I can't see **box-content** anywhere in this file. How does the code in _module.less generate the code from the second screenshot?? LESS is so frustrating compared to CSS :(

How am I supposed to change the **font-size** without simply overriding it or is it okay to override it? I hope some experienced LESS user can tell me the best way to solve this.

---

## Screenshots for answers:

[image]

Comment: I greated an issue on github magento2: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/27176

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I created a new file **THEME\web\css\source\lib\extend\_overrides.less** and imported it in my **_extend.less**:

```
@import 'lib/extend/_overrides';
```

Then I opened a shell and grepped for the string **abs-account-block-font-size**:

```
find . -name '*.less' -print0 | xargs -0 grep ".abs-account-block-font-size"
```

and I found the definition in **vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\web\css\source_extends.less**:

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
    .abs-account-block-font-size {
        .lib-font-size(16);
    }
}
```

So I added that piece of code into my **_overrides.less** and changed the font size to 10:

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
    .abs-account-block-font-size {
        .lib-font-size(10);
    }
}
```

> **HINT:** You should never add code directly into your **_extend.less**, because the file is ignored by "**grunt watch**". Only use the file for imports.

Answer (score 0):

1. create a new file `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/web/css/source/_extend.less`
2. add following content to the file:

`& when (@media-common = true) {
    .your-element-selector {
        .lib-font-size(10);
    }
}`

3. compile static

Comment: Does not work, it gets overriden by the original LESS code. Please see the last screenshot in my question. I need to override the original LESS somehow.